Exchange SAMLAssertion xml for access token to authenticate Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
I am building an application which fetch and upload documents to sharepoint , I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.
The application is enabled for azure Entra id SSO and successfully receiving the SAML response. Now I am trying to use the same saml xml to authenticate for sharepoint also so that I can access the site and document without asking user for sharepoint credetials again.
I tried to get the token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-c4ca-4cd0-8963-33034cd92c6c/oauth2/v2.0/token by passing the Base64 encoded SAML assertion but it throw error AADSTS50107: The requested federation realm object 'https://sts.windows.net/9387c2d2-c4ca-4cd0-8963-33034cd92c6c/' does not exist.
 this.Context = new ClientContext(configuration.Url)
 {
      Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(configuration.UserName, configuration.Password)
 };

for now I am using the SharePointOnlineCredentials with username and password, but I want to omit this and some how if SAML assertion can be used.
Note:- Access to sharepoint need to be user based, hence can not use dedicated identity

I'm pretty sure you can't reuse the SAML response for one service/app to another. I don't know how you can start a new auth flow for a user if you don't expose that service to the user. Can't you use a single dedicated identity for all users and then update the meta data fields of the uploaded document to link them to the logged in user?

@rene , that's the issue , I need the access on document and site as per the current user access, that's why I can not use dedicated identity.

Maybe wise to edit that constraint into the question because that is essential for an acceptable solution for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-token-exchange-saml-oauth

@identigral: Thats for the reference, It looks Clouser, but I am still not able to figure out how to do it in C#, the article is very short and without any example reference, Can you help me out please
